# Word problem "what number am I?"

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, word-problem

This is the word problem I cant figure out. Please help me

**What number am I?**

***HINT #1***

I am a number between 600-800

***HINT #2***

I am an odd number

***QUESTION***

I am Divisible by 3 primes < 15

Hint #1 + #2 = answer

***SOURCE QUESTION***

guess the number I am.

-between 600-800

-Divisible by 3 primes <15.

-Odd

-The first number and the third number add up to the middle number

Comment: I think your question would be more suitable for puzzles.stackexchange.com

Comment: Its a puzzle I dont know the answer to.

Comment: The correct link is www.puzzling.stackexchange.com  
Also the problem seems to be unclear. Do you have to find a single number or is there a different number for 1), 2) 3) ?

Comment: Are you looking for a single number which simultaneously satisfies all statements?  Or are you looking for multiple numbers, one for each statement.  Statement four doesn't make sense in the first interpretation, but the problem is incredibly trivial if the second interpretation.  Pick your favorite product of three prime numbers with each prime less than $15$ but the product being greater than $600$.  That will be the answer to #2.  Then, if your product was even, pick your favorite odd number less than the answer to #2 minus 600.  That will be #3.  Then #2-#3 gives you #1.

Comment: For example, 1) $700$, 2) $1001$, 3) $301$.  Indeed, $700$ is between $600$ and $800$, $1001=13\cdot 11\cdot 7$ is divisible by exactly three primes, $301$ is odd, and $700+301=1001$ is true.  As for the bonus points, "coolness" of sexy or twin primes is subjective.  Just name *any* sexy primes or twin primes.

Comment: If we were to ignore condition #4, and you are looking for a single number which satisfies all three of the first three conditions, then simple trial and error should find you an odd number between 600 and 800 which is divisible by exactly three primes less than 15.

Comment: @Теодор Дяков / JMoravitz

Ive edited the original post to try and clarify my question as best as possible, and included the original source material

Comment: Maybe Babak has it right and you mean to say the first **digit** plus the third **digit** equals the second **digit**.

Comment: The only primes < 15 are 2,3,5,7,11.  As the number is odd it isn't divisible by 2.  As the first and third digit add up to the second digit that is less than 10 and the first digit is 6 or 7 the third digit is less than 4 so it can't be 5.  Since the last digit is is not 5 or 0, the number isn't divisible by 5.  So the number is divisible by 3, 7 and 11.  So the number is divisible by 3*7*11 = 231.  There is only one number in the range of 600 to 800 that is divisible by 231.

Answer (score 2):

That would be $693=3^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11$.

Answer (score 2):

To provide justification for @Babak's answer:

Assuming the correct wording of the problem is:

- I am a three digit number
- I am between $600$ and $800$
- I am odd
- I have exactly three prime divisors less than fifteen
- My second digit equals the sum of my first digit and third digit

Our first digit must be either $6$ or $7$.  Our third digit must be small enough such that the first digit plus the third digit is less than or equal to nine.  Further, the third digit must be odd.  Our second digit must be the sum of the first and third digits.

This implies that the possible numbers ignoring the divisibility by primes requirement are $671, 693, 781$

Looking at the prime decomposition of each, $671 = 11\cdot 61$ only has one prime factor less than 15, $693 = 3^2\cdot 7\cdot 11$ has three prime factors less than 15, $781 = 11\cdot 71$ has only one prime factor less than 15.

Thus, the number we are searching for is indeed $693$ and there are no others satisfying the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The only primes less than 15 are 2,3,5,7,11 and this number is divisible by 3 of them.

====Edit.  ARRGGGH!! this simply isn't true.  I forgot 13!====

The number is odd so this number is not divisible by 2.

The first digit (call it $a$) plus the third digit (call it $c$) add up to the second (call it $b)

$a + c = b \le 9$ so $ c = b -a \le 9 - 6 = 3$.   So last digit is not $5$.  And as the number is odd the last digit is not $0$.

So the nummber is not divisible by $5$.

So the number is divisible by $3,7,11$

==== ARGH === no, it is divisible by $3,7,11$ or $3,7,13$ or $3, 11, 13$ or $7,11,13$====

So the number is divisible by $3*7*11 = 231$.

==== argh == or $3*7*13 = 273$  or $3*11*13= 429$ or $7*11*13=1001$ which is too big ====

$2*231 = 462 < 600$ and $4*231 = 924 > 800$.

So the number can only be $3*231 = 693$.

We can verify that $6+3 = 9$, that $600 < 693 < 800$, that $693$ is odd. And that $693 = 3^2*7*11$ is divisible by exactly 3 primes less than 15.

=== argh ===

$2*273 < 600$ and $4*273 > 800$ and $3*273 = 819$ doesn't work.

$429$ won't work either.  Take my word for it.

---

I might just delete this answer soon as it no longer is as slick and the other two answers are less calculation intensive.

Comment: You forgot to include $13$ in the list of primes less than $15$.

Comment: Son of a #@#@!  That's work aroundable.  But it completely ruins my entire purpose which was to slickly get the primes.  Guess it's still doable by noting it must be $671, 682, 693, 781, 792$ of which only $671, 693, 781$ are odd.  But that makes my answer.... redudent to the earlier ones.  Sigh....

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate.  You can still do it this way, but with one more prime the number of cases to rule out increases quite a bit.

Comment: Well, part of being "slick" was 5 and 2 were easy to rule out.  13 might be easy to rule out but it isn't as obvious.  (Actually, I'm not sure ruling out 13 is possible other than by trial and error.) Oh well.. JMoravitz answer will have to do.

Comment: Agreed.  Too bad the problem didn't use $12$ instead of $15$ for the limit on the primes.  (You might want to edit the answer with a preface to this effect.  The basic idea, I think, is too nice to delete the answer entirely.)